# STConvexHull() polygon from group of polygons

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to create a STConvexHull() polygon from group of polygons. And how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In SQL 2012, The `STConvexHull()` Method creates a polygon from any set of geometries (Excepts colinear points or colinear lines, which return a line.)

If you are using a .net language, you can do this via the programming language as well, and it will allow using the method to output into prior versions of SQL Server that support geometry, since it outputs a geometry, but you cannot use the function in SQL Server 2008 or 2008r2 directly.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933878.